# Mutate a value at a specific position in a column (Index) depending on a condition in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I am trying to `mutate()` a 0 or 1 at a specific position in a column. Normally `mutate()` just mutates the whole column but I want to check conditions and then place a value at a specific position. I tried to use something like an index. Hear is an example: I have values and want to compare them one by one. compare 10 to 16, 16 to 9 and so on. The criteria is: Are value 1 and 2 either both in a or not in a, or is one in a and the other value is not. I wrote down an approach but it seems like mutate does not allow to use `TaskS[i+1]`.

Thanks for your help!

| Index | Values | TaskS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  |
| 2 | 16 | 1 |
| 3 | 9 | 1 |
| 4 | 8 | 0 |

```
a <- c(1:10)
data_time_filter <- mutate(data_time_filter, TaskS = '')

for (i in 1:40){
  current <- data_time_filter$Trial_Id[i] %in% a
  adjacent <- data_time_filter$Trial_Id[i+1] %in% a
  if (current == adjacent){
    data_time_filter <- mutate(data_time_filter, TaskS[i+1] = 0)
  }
  else if (current != adjacent){
    data_time_filter <- mutate(data_time_filter, TaskS[i+1] = 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `TaskS` your expected output? Can you explain it? Why is row two and three 1 ?

Comment: @RonakShah I probably wasn't precise enough. So basically the values in 'Values' represent two categories: 1-10 and 11-20. My goal is to compare every value with the next value and check whether there is a change in the category (1 in TaskS) or no change in category (0 in TaskS). From 10 to 16 there is a change so I put 1 into the second row, same for 16 to 9. Comparing 9 to 8 there is no change. That is why there is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if I understand your question correctly but I will try to help anyway.

In my approach I have used a `user made function` in combination with `sapply`. I believe to work `mutate` correctly you need an `vector` output which you won't get with a `loop`.

So, here is what I did:

```
# Recreate df
data_time_filter <- data.frame(
  index = 1:4,
  Values = c(10, 16, 9, 8)
)

# Create filter
ff <- c(1:10)

# Add empty TakS column
data_time_filter <- data_time_filter %>% 
  mutate(TaskS = '')

# Define a function
abc <- function(data, filter){
  l <- length(data)
  
  sapply(1:l, function(x){
    if(x == 1){
      ""
    } else {
      current <- data[x-1] %in% filter 
      adjacent <- data[x] %in% filter
      if(current == adjacent){
        0
      } else {
        1
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This approach will let you use mutate:

```
> data_time_filter
  index Values TaskS
1     1     10      
2     2     16      
3     3      9      
4     4      8     

> data_time_filter %>% 
    mutate(TaskS = abc(Values, ff))
  index Values TaskS
1     1     10      
2     2     16     1
3     3      9     1
4     4      8     0
```

You could even skip making placeholder TaskS column and create a new one:

```
> data_time_filter %>% 
    mutate(TskS_new = abc(Values, ff))
  index Values TaskS TskS_new
1     1     10               
2     2     16              1
3     3      9              1
4     4      8              0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution worked perfectly. Basically we compute a vector with the comparisons using `sapply()`  which can then be mutated into the column TaskS? A comment above I tried to clarify the goal if you are interested.

Comment: Yeah that's it, `sapply()` let you create vectorized output. You could do it with `loop` too but I believe `sapply()` way is way much tidier. In addition I have packed in into function body so it is easy to use with `mutate`.